# Jackson deserialization fails after serializing an object using writeValueAsString

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, jackson, deserialization

Using the com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper class(com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.5) I am trying to deserialize an object of the following class:

```
class MyClass {

    String name;

    MyClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The code I am currently executing is the following:

```
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass("test");
    objectMapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
        .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
        .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
        .configure(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);

    String text = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myClass);
    objectMapper.readValue(text, MyClass.class);
```

which fails on the last line throwing the exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.pckge.MyClass` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
>    at [Source: (String)"{"name":"test"}"; line: 1, column: 2]

My goal would be to configure the object mapper so to successfully deserialize the object without using annotations such as JsonCreator or JsonProperties on the constructor of MyClass:

- Is this doable?
- Which configuration I am missing?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT 1: Reply by @Dean solves the issue. However I would like to avoid to have the default constructor also.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Jackson uses Getter and Setters to set values. So you need to modify your class:

```
class MyClass {

    String name;

    MyClass(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   MyClass(){}

   public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
   }

  public String getName(String name) {
     return this.name;
  }
}
```

Comment: This solves the issue. What if we do not want to create the default constructor?

Comment: Unfortunately it will require the default constructor.

Answer (score 26):

The proper way to solve this without a default constructor is to add JsonCreator and JsonProperty annotations to your class constructor.

```
class MyClass {

    String name;

    @JsonCreator
    MyClass(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's much better than adding NoArg constructor and public setters - the `name` field should be final!

Answer (score 7):

if you are using loombok remove the @Builder annotation of the class,  was my problem

Answer (score 2):

mine was to remove @Builder(Lombok) annotation from class and add @AllArgsConstructor and @NoArgsConstructor annotations, it worked

Comment: It also worked for me, but I cannot understand why, can you explain, please?

Answer (score 0):

I remove the @Builder(Lombok), it's worked, because @Builder create a private constructor.